# Unable to give no. of rows for table view having model class data?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am having json function below like to get the data from model class and to pass to the table view but the problem is how to give rows count so that in order to pass the data to the table view and here i need to give items model class count to the table view and here I am using table view for pagination so i am appending the data to the list class model can any one help me how to resolve this ?

```
 var listClassModel = [ModelClass]()

 func listCategoryDownloadJsonWithURL(listUrl: String) {
        let url = URL(string: listUrl)!
        print(listUrl)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil { print(error!); return }
            do {
                if let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String:Any] {
                    self.listClassModel.append(ModelClass(dict: jsonObj as [String : AnyObject]))
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
struct ModelClass {
    var items : [List]
    var totalCount : Int
    var searchCriteria : SearchCriteria

    init(dict:[String:AnyObject]) {
        totalCount = dict["total_count"] as! Int

        let searchDict = dict["search_criteria"] as? [String:AnyObject]
        searchCriteria = SearchCriteria(dict: searchDict!)

        let arr = dict["items"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]
        var listArr = [List]()
        for obj in arr! {
            listArr.append(List(dict: obj))
        }
        items = listArr
    }
}

struct List {

    let name : String
    let sku : Any
    let id : Int
    let attributeSetId : Int
    let price : Int
    let status : Int
    let visibility : Int
    let typeId: String
    let createdAt : Any
    let updatedAt : Any
    var customAttribute = [ListAttribute]()

    init(dict : [String:Any]) {
        if let customAttribute = dict["custom_attributes"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            var result = [ListAttribute]()
            for obj in customAttribute {
                result.append(ListAttribute(json: obj)!)
            }
            self.customAttribute = result
        } else {
            self.customAttribute = [ListAttribute]()
        }
        self.name = (dict["name"] as? String)!
        self.sku = dict["sku"]!
        self.id = (dict["id"] as? Int)!
        self.attributeSetId = (dict["attribute_set_id"] as? Int)!
        self.price = (dict["price"] as? Int)!
        self.status = (dict["status"] as? Int)!
        self.visibility = (dict["visibility"] as? Int)!
        self.typeId = (dict["type_id"] as? String)!
        self.createdAt = dict["created_at"]!
        self.updatedAt = dict["updated_at"]!
    }
}
struct SearchCriteria {
    var filterGroup : [FilterGroup]
    var sortGroup : [SortGroup]
    var pageSize : Int
    var pageNumber : Int

    init(dict:[String:AnyObject]) {
        if let arr = dict["filter_groups"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]{
            var filterArr = [FilterGroup]()
            for obj in arr {
                filterArr.append(FilterGroup(dict: obj))
            }
            self.filterGroup = filterArr
        } else {
            self.filterGroup = [FilterGroup]()
        }
        if let arr = dict["sort_orders"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]{
            var filterArr = [SortGroup]()
            for obj in arr {
                filterArr.append(SortGroup(dict: obj))
            }
            self.sortGroup = filterArr
        } else {
            self.sortGroup = [SortGroup]()
        }
        self.pageSize = dict["page_size"] as! Int
        self.pageNumber = dict["current_page"] as! Int
    }
}
```

Below is the code for table view

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let arr = listClassModel[section].items
        return arr.count
    }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "productsCell", for: indexPath) as! productsCell
        let arr = listClassModel[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
        let images = listCategoryImageArray[indexPath.row]
        let urls = NSURL(string: images)
        self.tableView.isHidden = false
        cell.productImage.hnk_setImageFromURL(urls! as URL)
        cell.productName.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        cell.productName.numberOfLines = 2
        cell.productName.text = arr.name
        cell.productPrice.text = "$\( (arr.price)).00"
        cell.buynowButton .addTarget(self, action: #selector(buyNowButton(_:)), for:UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        cell.cartButton .addTarget(self, action: #selector(cartButton(_:)), for:UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Hi
According to your code the listClassModel is array right ?
And if its an array then you just need to write - 'return  listClassModel.count'

Comment: and if you want to show data like section wise then you need to change your logic for save values

Comment: no not section wise i need  to show only items model class count @Anita

Comment: @user what is the error given by compiler?

Comment: if not how to change it to get listclassmodel.items.count from the saved data and i need to have pagination also for this so i changed it as array

Comment: try to take listClassModel as NSMutableArray 
Initialize it
Add objects in it
And return listClassModel.count in numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: it's crashing in no.or rows in section method @TusharSharma

Comment: @user what is the crash?

Comment: fatal error index out of range @TusharSharma

Comment: add cellforrowatindexpah code also, u accesing out of bounds value

Comment: @user Do you even have count in array?

Comment: in array one model class and inside that two model classes @TusharSharma

Comment: @user can you print the count value and check when it crashes?

Comment: the problem is i need to give the items count that is list struct class count in no. of rows in section but when i give like then i need to change my line var listclassmodel : modelclass? if i change i may able to give but unable to add data during pagination @TusharSharma

Comment: how to take it as nsmutablearray ? @Anita

Comment: Why not !! 
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];

arr.add(ModelClass(dict: jsonObj as [String : AnyObject]))

NSLog(arr.count):

In number of row return arr.count

I hav return in objective c code structure please use your swift when you code

Thanks